# Creating a "execute-api" interface VPC endpoint for one private API Gateway breaks all public API Gateways access from the VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to make one of our API Gateways private and add it to the VPN. Reading the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html), I need to add an interface VPC endpoint. I've done this with the following terraform:

```
data "aws_vpc_endpoint_service" "execute-api" {
  service = "execute-api"
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "gateway-endpoint" {
  vpc_id              = data.aws_vpc.shared.id
  service_name        = data.aws_vpc_endpoint_service.execute-api.service_name
  vpc_endpoint_type   = "Interface"
  private_dns_enabled = true

  subnet_ids         = toset(data.aws_subnets.private.ids)
  security_group_ids = toset([data.aws_security_group.default.id])
}
```

I was then happily setting up my API Gateway to make it private, adding the Resource Policy etc.

However everyone else on the team was going through hell because things were suddenly breaking unexpectedly.

Turns out, every other API Gateway (configurations completely unchanged) were returning 403s, seems me adding an `execute-api` interface to the VPC affected ALL API Gateways in the account!

These other API Gateways were not in private mode, they were "Edge Optimised", and not within the VPC:

[image]

However, they were suddenly not accessible unless the lambdas were taken outside of the VPC. Is there something I'm missing that creating this endpoint would block public gateways accessing lambdas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a little late, but I had the exact same issue and wanted to share some resources for those in the future who encounter this (I just made this account specifically to answer).

**Context**

When this happened to me, I discovered that the VPC Endpoint I created via Terraform covered the generic domain `*.execute-api.<your-region>.amazonaws.com`. I was able to see this in the AWS console, as in Terraform I had only specified the `execute-api` service.

This domain is used by **all** of the APIs in API Gateway as the default invoke URL. The "*" above is filled in by your API's unique ID (Example invoke URL for an API usually looks like: `https://abcdefg.execute-api.<your-region>.amazonaws.com`).

A VPC Interface Endpoint is what I had setup, and according [to the docs on VPC Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/aws-privatelink/what-are-vpc-endpoints.html):

> Interface endpoints enable connectivity to services over AWS PrivateLink. ... An interface endpoint is a collection of one or more elastic network interfaces with a private IP address that serves as an entry point for traffic destined to a supported service.

From my limited understanding of networking concepts, this meant to me that the entire `execute-api` "service" in AWS was now going to route through this VPC endpoint. All of my public and private APIs use this `execute-api` service as part of the invoke URL. And because I had private DNS enabled, any calls outside of the VPC to one of my public APIs was just going to fail. Notice that if you switch off the private DNS enabled on the VPC Endpoint, the public APIs will work again, but the private APIs will now break.

**Potential Solution: Custom Domains for Public APIs**

One option I found was to switch the public APIs to use custom domains, so that they no longer utilize that generic `execute-api` domain. You can read more about that here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html

Using custom domains for public APIs means that only your private APIs use that default `execute-api` service, so you can keep your VPC Endpoint as it is.

Additionally, here are some instructions on setting up Route 53 records for API gateway custom domains: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-api-gateway.html

**Summary**

This was a frustrating issue for me as well, hope this helps someone find the issue much sooner than I had...